# Localisation via resx in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, resx

There are many questions about it but still haven't read a solution for me

I have all my resources in a seperate project and this project has a Resource folder with 3 languages in it.

In any control I have in the constructor a call to InitializeLanguage()
where I set the right text for the right language like this:

```
public void InitializeLanguage()
    {
        bOK.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Ok;
        cbSM.Text = Lastenboek.Language.SamenvattendeMeetstaat;
        cbDM.Text = Lastenboek.Language.DetailMeetstaat;
        cbDMHeadingStyles.Text = Lastenboek.Language.KopStijlen;
        cbExportArtikelsZonderMeetstaat.Text = Lastenboek.Language.ArtikelsZonderMeetstaat;
        cbSMHeadingStyles.Text = Lastenboek.Language.KopStijlen;
        cbRamingsPrijs.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Ramingsprijs;
        cbBeknopteOmschrijving.Text = Lastenboek.Language.BeknopteOmschrijving;
        cbFaseSM.Text = Lastenboek.Language.GesplitstOpFase;
        groupBox3.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Filter;
        label2.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Tot;
        label1.Text = Lastenboek.Language.DatumVan;
        gbPrijzen.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Prijzen;
        label3.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Account;
        cbTotaalSM.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Totaal;
        groupBox4.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Template;
        label4.Text = Lastenboek.Language.Layout;
        Text = Lastenboek.Language.ExporteerMeetstaat;
    }
```

Everything works fine but now sometimes the label is too small for the text in other languages. Is there a good way to change the language at designtime and change the dimensions for different languages?

Comment: Have you tried the Label.Autosize property? [Label.AutoSize Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: they are all set to autosize but they overlap other controls

Comment: I suppose you can always get the TextBox.Text.Length property and adjust the Width..

Comment: sorry edited my previous answer: they overlap other controls so i have to change the locations of the other controls.

Comment: Yes they do, that's why they came up with WPF and discontinued Windows Forms..

Comment: I know and when I have to change a lot to a form I convert it to WPF but it's an older project so a lot of work to change everything to wpf

Comment: Spinning your own custom localization scheme is never not a mistake.  And not just because of the butt-ugly code you have to write, you can't ask anybody to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And you don't even need to programmatically set localized texts/images and other values.

Just set `Localizable` property on your form to `true` and then you can switch languages at design time and edit everything for that language at design time.

When you start the application the form will use the Windows language. If you want to change it programmatically just set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property. You might want to repoen your form to apply the language or call `InitializeComponent()` explicitly.

Comment: I know this is an option but then you have resx files per form or control.
I have all my resources for one language in one seperate resx file in an other project

Comment: Of course, and that is the preferred way of localization. They will be compiled into your assembly so you don't need to deploy the .resx files.

Comment: Indeed but now I have the problem I can't change the language at design time and can't change the size and location per language

Comment: _Of course, and that is the preferred way of localization_ - Not agree. With resource file for every form, you will end up with common text which have duplicated values in other forms. Imagine you want change word `"Done"` to `"Complete"` and it's translations too. In case when all forms contains this word, you will need go through all forms to update

Comment: @Fabio: Imagine you have "Home", "Year", "Season" or such words on different forms which should be translated differently in many languages depending on the context. Earlier we used a global "translater" engine, too, then ended up to prefix _every_ resource key by location to make them unique, even OK and Cancel. The engine could remove these prefixes to find a fallback translation but it turned out it is better to use the preferred way. Yes, even if there are duplications.

Comment: In this case you will use different resource key for different context. **I say nothing about "translater" engine.** My point was that having all translation in one separated project will make little bid easier to maintain them. When you use "your preferred" way in cases when you need to use translation in "business layer" you will end up with referencing forms or creating another resource file. Responsibility of `Form` (read "View") is displaying data. And responsibility of "business layer" to provide this data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have dynamic texts for controls, but you want to have "hardcode" fixed control sizes for every language.

with this approach maintaining can be complicated. Every change in translation should be tested in UI - is it fit or not in the control.

Another approach will be support "AutoSize" for controls. Winforms have `TableLayoutPanel` control, which can be useful for controls with dynamic texts.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "TableLayoutPanel", which MSFT even recommends for localization. See "How to: Support Localization on Windows Forms Using AutoSize and the TableLayoutPanel Control" currently found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zkt8b33(v=vs.90).aspx. In practice though it takes some effort to wrap your head around it. Getting it to work and in combination with certain other properties can be frustrating (and creates a learning curve for those who later have to support it, even yourself months or years later). It does the job though (for the most part).